# How to Convert Climate API into as WMS / WFS Layers for advanced analytics

Tags: api, leaflet, geoserver, openweathermap, wms

I'm trying to access openweathermap api forecast, in somepoint I need to take decision based on the climatic layers so kindly help me to convert as WFS Layer(Geoserver) from the api. Thanks. I'm JS Beginner know Leaflet and Geoserver

Comment: please provide more information about your issues. please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say much about what the API in question returns. If it is a WFS itself then you can cascade it through your GeoServer instance, which will allow you to serve it out as a WFS and a WMS.

If it returns some other format, you can write a custom datastore by following the steps in this [tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/datastore.html). When you have a working jar package you can drop it into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and restart GeoServer and it should appear as a new datastore.